# Who to contact to get a Forge app white-listed for Fusion Team?

Tags: autodesk-forge

(Not exactly a programming question, but the programming issues have led to this requirement)...

Who at Autodesk do we need to contact to get a Forge app white-listed for Fusion Team?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking for whitelisting your client id for the Fusion team. You should be able to access it with the 3-legged access token without any problem. Could you share the details?

Comment: Hi Eason.  It turns out that the answer to my question here is that I needed to contact you.  And we have already been going back-and-forth in an email thread working to resolve this (request 7202).